# Wifi and ethernet issues Asus ROG Zephyrus G15 GA503

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 21.10

My computer which is running Ubuntu 21.10 is not recognizing my wireless interface as shown by

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Though my hardware is at least recognized given this shortened output of lspci

```
$ lspci -v
04:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device 4680
    Physical Slot: 0-1
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 78, IOMMU group 13
    Memory at fe20300000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at fe20400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at fe20404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [e0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [f8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1556 Rev=1 Len=008 <?>
    Capabilities: [108] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [110] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
```

For my wireless card some people said they fixed the problem by upgrading their kernel to **+5.12** but that did not work for me. As you can see I am running 5.13.

```
$ uname -a
Linux nick 5.13.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 15 14:21:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also verified that the correct Kernel module is being loaded (**mt7921e**) and it indeed is

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               16384  0
isofs                  45056  0
bnep                   28672  2
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      24576  1 intel_rapl_msr
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   147456  1
mt7921e                77824  0
kvm_amd               126976  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  2
mt76_connac_lib        36864  1 mt7921e
kvm                   872448  1 kvm_amd
btusb                  61440  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
snd_hda_intel          53248  5
btintel                32768  1 btusb
nouveau              2084864  1
mt76                   77824  2 mt7921e,mt76_connac_lib
amdgpu               6385664  7
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
bluetooth             663552  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
aesni_intel           376832  0
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
mac80211             1024000  3 mt76,mt7921e,mt76_connac_lib
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_hda_codec         147456  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
input_leds             16384  0
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
rapl                   20480  0
snd_hda_core           94208  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
iommu_v2               24576  1 amdgpu
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
joydev                 28672  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
gpu_sched              36864  1 amdgpu
drm_ttm_helper         16384  2 amdgpu,nouveau
ttm                    69632  3 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,nouveau
hid_multitouch         28672  0
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
efi_pstore             16384  0
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_pcm               118784  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
drm_kms_helper        262144  2 amdgpu,nouveau
cfg80211              892928  4 mt76,mt7921e,mac80211,mt76_connac_lib
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       20480  0
snd_pci_acp3x          20480  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
cec                    53248  1 drm_kms_helper
rc_core                57344  1 cec
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,nouveau
snd                    94208  21 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ccp                   102400  1 kvm_amd
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  1 snd
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
typec_ucsi             45056  1 ucsi_acpi
typec                  57344  1 typec_ucsi
mac_hid                16384  0
asus_wireless          20480  0
amd_pmc                20480  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  1
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             45056  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   561152  11 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,ttm,nouveau
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_asus               28672  0
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            73728  2 uas
usbhid                 61440  1 hid_asus
hid_generic            16384  0
mfd_aaeon              16384  0
asus_wmi               40960  3 asus_nb_wmi,hid_asus,mfd_aaeon
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
sdhci_pci              65536  0
i2c_hid_acpi           16384  0
nvme                   45056  2
cqhci                  32768  1 sdhci_pci
i2c_hid                28672  1 i2c_hid_acpi
xhci_pci               20480  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
nvme_core             126976  3 nvme
i2c_piix4              28672  0
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
sdhci                  69632  1 sdhci_pci
wmi                    32768  5 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  53248  2 asus_wmi,nouveau
hid                   135168  5 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic,hid_asus
```

I am not sure what the problem is and could use some help. Thank you.

Comment: Let's see what the message log has to say. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep -i mt7` Welcome to sk Ubuntu.

Comment: Same issue for me. I tried jumping between different kernel versions (5.xx) and Ubuntu versions (20.xx, 21.xx). Ethernet was completely unrecognized/absent in all of them. Got WiFi to work, but only when I start without power adapter plugged in(!?)

Comment: See also this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673830/no-ethernet-or-wifi-settings-on-fedora-ubuntu-elementary-linux-fresh-install?newreg=f21b8349cecd41cbb8c4d3225522bc20